# Shutdown problem on Lenovo G50 after installing Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: networking, linux-mint, shutdown

After installing successfully Linux Mint 17.3 on Lenovo G50, its not rebooted.
The error is :

```
[397.188708] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
[400.538090] init: mdm main process (2363) killed by KILL signal
[400.546181] init: wait-for-state (playmouth-shutdowndm) main process (29255) killed by  TERM signal
```

After that it hangs there. Even if I do force shutdown then the network connection (LAN) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnecting your router or LAN before shutting down. In one of my questions, someone suggested that it might be the problem, due to remote unreachable servers. If that doesnt help, try running `journalctl --boot -1 -e --full` and edit your question and paste the output there. This command will tell ppl what systemd thought it was doing.